# how to remove partial duplicates from a data frame?

Tags: r

Data I'm importing describes numeric measurements taken at various locations for more or less evenly spread timestamps.  sometimes this "evenly spread" is not really true and I have to discard some of the values, it's not that important which one, as long as I have one value for each timestamp for each location.

what I do with the data?  I add it to a `result` data.frame.  There I have a `timestamp` column and the values in the timestamp column, they are definitely evenly spaced according to the `step`.

```
timestamps <- ceiling(as.numeric((timestamps-epoch)*24*60/step))*step*60 + epoch
result[result$timestamp %in% timestamps, columnName] <- values
```

---

This does NOT work when I have timestamps that fall in the same time step.  This is an example:

```
> data.frame(ts=timestamps, v=values)
                   ts         v
1 2009-09-30 10:00:00 -2.081609
2 2009-09-30 10:04:18 -2.079778
3 2009-09-30 10:07:47 -2.113531
4 2009-09-30 10:09:01 -2.124716
5 2009-09-30 10:15:00 -2.102117
6 2009-09-30 10:27:56 -2.093542
7 2009-09-30 10:30:00 -2.092626
8 2009-09-30 10:45:00 -2.086339
9 2009-09-30 11:00:00 -2.080144
> data.frame(ts=ceiling(as.numeric((timestamps-epoch)*24*60/step))*step*60+epoch,
+ v=values)
                   ts         v
1 2009-09-30 10:00:00 -2.081609
2 2009-09-30 10:15:00 -2.079778
3 2009-09-30 10:15:00 -2.113531
4 2009-09-30 10:15:00 -2.124716
5 2009-09-30 10:15:00 -2.102117
6 2009-09-30 10:30:00 -2.093542
7 2009-09-30 10:30:00 -2.092626
8 2009-09-30 10:45:00 -2.086339
9 2009-09-30 11:00:00 -2.080144
```

in Python I would (mis)use a dictionary to achieve what I need:

```
dict(zip(timestamps, values)).items()
```

returns a list of pairs where the first coordinate is unique.

in R I don't know how to do it in a compact and efficient way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would use `subset` combined with `duplicated` to filter non-unique timestamps in the second data frame:

```
R> df_ <- read.table(textConnection('
                     ts         v
1 "2009-09-30 10:00:00" -2.081609
2 "2009-09-30 10:15:00" -2.079778
3 "2009-09-30 10:15:00" -2.113531
4 "2009-09-30 10:15:00" -2.124716
5 "2009-09-30 10:15:00" -2.102117
6 "2009-09-30 10:30:00" -2.093542
7 "2009-09-30 10:30:00" -2.092626
8 "2009-09-30 10:45:00" -2.086339
9 "2009-09-30 11:00:00" -2.080144
'), as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE)

R> subset(df_, !duplicated(ts))
                   ts      v
1 2009-09-30 10:00:00 -2.082
2 2009-09-30 10:15:00 -2.080
6 2009-09-30 10:30:00 -2.094
8 2009-09-30 10:45:00 -2.086
9 2009-09-30 11:00:00 -2.080
```

**Update:** To select a specific value you can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df_$v, by=list(df_$ts), function(x) x[1])  # first value
aggregate(df_$v, by=list(df_$ts), function(x) tail(x, n=1))  # last value
aggregate(df_$v, by=list(df_$ts), function(x) max(x))  # max value
```

Comment: this works, thanks!  but how did you find it in the documentation?  not even now that I know the answer do I manage to guess where to look!  ALSO: imagine I did want to choose which value (say, the last one), does subset offer the possibility?

Comment: one addition: 'subset' can also be used to remove duplicates from vectors?  if so, how?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking at data structures for time-indexed objects, and not for a dictionary.  For the former, look at the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) and [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) packages which offer much better time-pased subsetting:

```
R> library(xts)
R> X <- xts(data.frame(val=rnorm(10)), \
            order.by=Sys.time() + sort(runif(10,10,300)))
R> X
                        val
2009-11-20 07:06:17 -1.5564
2009-11-20 07:06:40 -0.2960
2009-11-20 07:07:50 -0.4123
2009-11-20 07:08:18 -1.5574
2009-11-20 07:08:45 -1.8846
2009-11-20 07:09:47  0.4550
2009-11-20 07:09:57  0.9598
2009-11-20 07:10:11  1.0018
2009-11-20 07:10:12  1.0747
2009-11-20 07:10:58  0.7062
R> X["2009-11-20 07:08::2009-11-20 07:09"]
                        val
2009-11-20 07:08:18 -1.5574
2009-11-20 07:08:45 -1.8846
2009-11-20 07:09:47  0.4550
2009-11-20 07:09:57  0.9598
R>
```

The `X` object is ordered by a time sequence -- make sure it is of type POSIXct so you may need to parse your dates first.  Then we can just index for '7:08 to 7:09 on the give day'.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to remove duplicates.  I don't do much with the timestamps.  thanks for pointing me to this library, but I think I prefer not adding dependencies.

Comment: Look at unique() and duplicated() for that, and still use POSIXct types.

Comment: about POSIXct types, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803627/ helps understanding why Dirk Eddelbuettel suggests using it.