# Get a Different Column for Each Row of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

I have a `data.frame` with an arbitrary number of columns and I need a way to grab different columns (just one) from each row.  For instance if I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
myDF <- data.frame(A=letters[1:5], B=letters[6:10], C=LETTERS[26:22], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to grab the letters a, g, c, W and V.

If this were a `matrix` it would be easy to solve.

```
myDF[cbind(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3))]
```

But I have to store the data in a `data.frame` because the data is often a `POSIXlt` and I have not found a way to convert a `data.frame` of those to a `matrix`.

Does anyone have a good way of doing this without looping row-by-row?  I have many failed attempts that I'd be happy to share.

Comment: What version of R are you using?  Your code works just fine since at least R-2.14.2. Also, coming soon, (and already in R-devel, according to it's NEWS file), "Matrix indexing of dataframes by two column numeric indices is now supported for replacement as well as extraction."

Comment: R 2.15.0.  You're right, the code works as is for the example, but not when the data are `POSIXlt`.  Perhaps I should edit the question to have the data be `POSIXlt`.

Comment: POSIXlt should be converted to POSIXct before doing ANYTHING.

Comment: -1 for posting an example that did not illustrate the problem.

Comment: @DWin Based on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803627/understanding-dates-times-posixc-and-posixct-in-r) it does seem that `POSIXct` will make my life a lot easier.  Unfortunately, I will not have the option of switching to `POSIXct` and will have to work with any sort of `POSIX` or `Date` or whatever is sent my way.

Comment: If the expected or acceptable granularity of the data would be at the date level, then it might be even easier to use the Date class. If not, then you should edit your post to reflect the complexity that you expect.

Comment: If you are willing to have the components of the POSIXlt class objects in separate columns of a matrix, you should say so, but there is no way to store objects that have attributes in matrices. Run this code: pp <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()); pp; matrix(pp,1); attributes(pp)

Comment: @DWin Can't expect the data to come in at a date level, POSIXlt, POSIXct or even quarter.  Has to be generic and I can't force any conversion.  The solution in my answer below gets the job done regardless of data type, so it is probably going to win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ineloquent, but it works for dates which are particularly difficult:

```
vect <- do.call(c, args=as.list(myDF))
vect[(1:NROW(myDF)) + NROW(myDF) * (c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3) - 1)]
```