# Display only one line for each NA Value

Tags: r, dataframe

At some point in my script I like to see the number of `missing values`
in my `data.frame` and display them.
In my case I have:

```
out <- read.csv(file="...../OUT.csv", na.strings="NULL")

sum(is.na(out$codeHelper))

out[is.na(out$codeHelper),c(1,length(colnames(out)))]
```

It works perfectly fine.
However, the last command obviously gives me the whole `data.frame` where the `NA` is `TRUE`, eg:

```
5561                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5562                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5563                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5564                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5565                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5566                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5567                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5568                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
5601 Zaire (Democ Republic Congo) <NA>
5602 Zaire (Democ Republic Congo) <NA>
5603 Zaire (Democ Republic Congo) <NA>
5604 Zaire (Democ Republic Congo) <NA>
5605 Zaire (Democ Republic Congo) <NA>
```

With a big frame and a lot of NAs that looks pretty messy.
Important to me is only where the NA occurs i.e which country 
(in the second column) has a missing value in the third column.

So how can i only display a single row for each country?

It should look something like this:

```
    1                  Yemen (PDR) <NA>
    2 Zaire (Democ Republic Congo) <NA>
    3                          USA <NA>
    4                     W. Samoa <NA>
```

Comment: Use `ncol(x)` instead of `length(colnames(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique(c(1,2,3,4,4))`

will give you

> 1 2 3 4

so

`unique(out[is.na(out$codeHelper),c(1,length(colnames(out)))])`

should be what you're looking for?

Comment: perfect, i was exactly searching for such a function! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
subset(dataframe.name, !duplicated(country.colname),
       select=c(col1.name, col2.name, ...))
```

see also this related question: [how to remove partial duplicates from a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769365/how-to-remove-partial-duplicates-from-a-data-frame)